# How to create infinite nested sub menus?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am trying to write a module.Its menu management module that you can create menu and sub menus how many that you want.
But now in my module your menu depth can be until three.It means my module supports a root menu and the child for it and the child for the child at the maximum but I am thinking about an algorithm to create infinite nested sub menus and how to show them in the site.I mean I want to set the user free to create infinite nested sub menus.I dont know how should my models and database been set to achieve my goal.I am using MVC3 and C# and entity framework.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you looking for a UI component, a database model, what?

Comment: @Rob As I said in my question I am asking for an algorithm.Not in high details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as data model, you could have:

- Id
- MenuText
- Url
- ParentId

For top-level menu items the ParentId would be NULL. Otherwise, it points to the parent.

Most UI menus (like Superfish.js) use `<ul>` and `<li>` elements to render menus. Just iterate through your menu items in your database to build out the `<ul>` structure.

Here is a start:

```
private void BuildMenu()
{
    List<MenuItem> menuItems = GetTopLevelMenuItems();

    string html = "<ul>";

    foreach (var menuItem in menuItems)
    {
        html += BuildMenuSubMenu(menuItem);
    }
    html += "</ul>"
}

private string BuildMenuSubMenu(MenuItem menuItem)
{
    string html = string.Empty;

    List<MenuItem> childItems = GetChildItems(menuItem);

    html += string.Format("<li><a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", menuItem.Url, menuItem.MenuText);

    if (childItems.Count > 0)
    {
        html += "<ul>";
        foreach (var child in childItems)
        {
            html += BuildMenuSubMenu(child);
        }
        html += "<ul>";
    }

    html += "<li>";

    return html;
}
```

Comment: Yes but my problem is just here.For making <ul> and <li> I use foreach.For example if I have a three depth menu it needs there foreach to make it with <ul> and <li>.But now we have infinite depth of menu.So how can I make them in UI?

Comment: Post the code you have so far. It's probably easy enough to make a recursive method to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public List<_Category> GetTopLevelMenuItems() 
    { 
       entityName db = new entityName();
       var categories = db.Category.Where(x => x.CategoryID == null).Select(x => new _Category() { 
    ID = x.ID,
    CategoryName = x.CategoryName

    }).ToList();

    return categories;
    }

    public List<_Category> GetChildItems(_Category C)
    {

        entityName db = new entityName();
        var categories = db.Category.Where(x => x.CategoryID == C.ID).Select(x => new _Category()
        {
            ID = x.ID,
            CategoryName = x.CategoryName,


        }).ToList();
        return categories;
    }
    public string BuildMenu()
    {
        List<_Category> menuItems = GetTopLevelMenuItems();

        string html = "<ul>";

        foreach (var menuItem in menuItems)
        {
            html += BuildMenuSubMenu(menuItem);
        }
        html += "</ul>";
        return html;
    }
    public string BuildMenuSubMenu(_Category menuItem)
    {
        string html = string.Empty;

        List<_Category> childItems = GetChildItems(menuItem);

        html += string.Format("<li><a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", menuItem.ID, menuItem.CategoryName);

        if (childItems.Count > 0)
        {
            html += "<ul>";
            foreach (var child in childItems)
            {
                html += BuildMenuSubMenu(child);
            }
            html += "</ul>";

        }

        html += "</li>";

        return html;
    }
public class _Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

- Edited Full Code

Using in ActionResult:

```
ViewData["menu"] = BuildMenu();
```